# Icons not working in .desktop file

Tags: 20.04, icons, unity-dash, .desktop

I wanted the program Arduino to be accessible from the dash, so I put this in `~/.local/share/applications/arduino.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Arduino IDE
GenericName=Arduino IDE
Comment=Open-source electronics prototyping platform
Exec=/home/username/Programmer/arduino/arduino
Icon=arduino
Terminal=false
Categories=Development;IDE;Electronics;
MimeType=text/x-arduino;
Keywords=embedded electronics;electronics;avr;microcontroller;
StartupWMClass=processing-app-Base
```

I have a transparent png icon (600 x 315 pixels) called arduino.png in the same directory, but it didn't work. It says [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/icons.html.en) :

> Application icons should be available at least at a resolution of
> 48x48 pixels. Place the icon in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/`

So I put it there, too, but I still don't have an Arduino icon associated with the desktop entry. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the arduino.png icon into the same folder as the application binary, then...

Edit your arduino.desktop file and...

Change this:

```
Icon=arduino
```

To this:

```
Icon=/home/username/Programmer/arduino/arduino.png
```

Save the edit.

If you decide to put the arduino.desktop file on the ~/Desktop, right-click on the arduino.desktop file, and select "Allow Launching".

Launch arduino using the normal <kbd>SUPER</kbd> key method, and once the icon appears in the dock, right-click on the icon, and select **Add to favorites**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can simply write full path to the icon in corresponding line:

```
Icon=/usr/share/app-install/icons/arduino.png
```